# How to find location of link in Excel workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel book that, when opened, gives the warning:

```
This workbook contains links to other data sources.
```

I want to remove all of these links so that the warning will not be triggered.  Thinking that any external link will be of the form `'[workbook path]'!address`  I used this code:

```
Sub ListLinks()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim link As Variant
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each link In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    Debug.Print link
Next link

End Sub
```

This returned a file path:

```
\\somePath\xyz\aWorkbook.xlsm
```

I searched all formulas in the workbook for this string using Ctrl+F, but no results were returned.  How do I find and remove this link?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a link in a formula, it could be the entire sheet or book is linked to a database file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the links is not enough to suppress the warning.  On the **Edit Links** window, I clicked **Startup Prompt** and set the radio button to "Don't display the alert and don't update automatic links".  This successfully prevented the warning from appearing.

Answer (score 3):

Your workbook could be linking via a named range pointing to another workbook. A search of formulas for the linked workbook may find nothing because the link is hidden in the name.

Check your named ranges for links to other workbooks.

Answer (score 3):

Could be in one of these?:

- [HYPERLINKS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-workbook-links-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1) (formula and normal)
- [NAME MANAGER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4)
- [DATA VALIDATION](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249)
- [CONDITIONAL FORMATTING](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/highlight-patterns-and-trends-with-conditional-formatting-eea152f5-2a7d-4c1a-a2da-c5f893adb621)
- BUTTON WITH [MACRO](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-a-macro-ed9e8c3d-58fd-47a1-83eb-bdee680376bb) (still pointing to originating macro)

Comment: This one is the complete answer and it worked for me. Apparently the "remove links" button will not break the "inner links" (because things will stop working without your notice), so you need to review one by one these items to see if you have any links there.

Answer (score 1):

The following loop should work.

```
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim varLink As Variant

'Define variable as an Excel link type.
varLink = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

'Are there any links?
If IsArray(varLink) = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Break the links in the active workbook.
For intCounter = 1 To UBound(varLink)
    ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink _
    Name:=varLink(intCounter), _
    Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
Next intCounter
```

Comment: I ran that, saved and closed the workbook, and got the warning again when I re-opened it.

Comment: Have you checked the data connections to see if there is a connection to a database as mentioned by @Chrismas007.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after removing all the links as described above, I then found that some of my validation data was refering to other workbooks. After correcting this the problem disappeared.